# Mysql запрос php

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста что не так.
PHP:

```
 $db = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","1234")
 or die("<p>Ошибка подключения к базе данных! " . mysql_error() . "</p>");
 mysql_select_db ("test",$db)
 or die("<p>Ошибка выбора базы данных! ". mysql_error() . "</p>");
```

это файл bd.php для доступа в базу
В целях безопасности ввел другие данные.
PHP:

```
include ('bd.php');
 $Name = $_POST['Name'];
 $Date = $_POST['Date'];
 $Date_2 = $_POST['Date_2'];
 $Decision = $_POST['Decision'];
 $sql = 'INSERT INTO test_tab (Name, Date, Date_2, Decision,) VALUES ("'.$Name.'", "'.$Date.'", "'.$Date_2.'", "'.$Decision.'")';
// проверка
 if(!mysql_query($sql))
 {echo '<center><p><b>Ошибка при добавлении данных!</b></p></center>';}
 else
 {echo '<center><p><b>Данные добавлены!</b></p></center>';}
```

Выдает Ошибка при добавлении данных! хотя все данные ввожу и в форме все имена совпадают, подскажите в чем беда

Comment: Нравится когда опытные программисты без гонора и упрека указывают на ошибки), а новички или те кто спрашивают совета благодарят. Это хороший тон общения что на форумах, что в жизни на работе. Все мы были когда-то зелеными)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас построен не правильный SQL запрос.

> `$sql = 'INSERT INTO test_tab (Name, Date, Date_2, Decision,) VALUES ("'.$Name.'", "'.$Date.'", "'.$Date_2.'", "'.$Decision.'")';`

Используйте:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `test_tab` (`Name`, `Date`, `Date_2`, `Decision`) VALUES ("'.$Name.'", "'.$Date.'", "'.$Date_2.'", "'.$Decision.'")';
```

Да и пригляните лучше в сторону [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 3):

[deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

```
Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
функции:
```

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

**Обновление**

sqlInjection у вас там в полный рост. чтобы понять что за ошибка - печатайте mysql_error();